# createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, archlinux, createuser

I installed [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) on [archlinux](/questions/tagged/archlinux) using this command:

```
sudo pacman -S postgresql
```

And it installed OK. But when I want to create a new user, like this:

```
sudo -iu postgres
[postgres@amirashabani ~]$ createuser amirashabani
```

I receive this error:

```
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot to `start` and `enable` the [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) service, which was mentioned in the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL):

> Finally, [start](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Start) and [enable](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Enable) the postgresql.service.

After doing this:

```
systemctl start postgresql.service
systemctl enable postgresql.service
```

Everything worked fine.